# Inserting information found in a batch script into the registry

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, wmic, registrykey

I have a .reg file that inserts some info into the System properties. I would like to add the computer model to this also.
This is the current script bellow. I would like to insert the Manufacturer and the model number in here automatically if possible.

the model and manufacturer can be found using command prompt with the following commands

```
wmic computersystem get model
wmic computersystem get manufacturer
```

i would like to know how i can automatically insert the results into the .reg file bellow so that the script will work for different models ect.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation]
"Logo"="c:\\OEM\\OEMLOGO.BMP"
"Manufacturer"="example"
"Model"="example"
"SupportHours"="8:30am - 5:00pm"
"SupportPhone"="0458228893"
"SupportURL"="www.web.com.au"
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you want to capture and work with the output of a command, use a `for /F` loop.

```js
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('command') do set "var=%%~I"
```

... or similar.  However, WMI queries are a little tricky, in that results are displayed in an odd encoding (UCS-2 LE, if I recall correctly); so capturing the output of `wmic` requires a little more care.

One trick is to query an extra column, then ignore it.  Then the columns you want aren't affected by the tricksy encoding.  In this case,

```js
for /f "tokens=2-3 delims=," %%I in (
    'wmic computersystem get manufacturer^,model^,status /format:csv'
) do (
    set "manufacturer=%%~I"
    set "model=%%~J"
)
```

... should get you the values you need into variables you can use.  Since column 1 is your computer name and column 4 is the "Status" column, you can just drop those and end up with your intended values uninfluenced by any beginning-of-line or end-of-line encoding quirks.

From there, it's just a simple matter of

```js
set "branch=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation"
reg add "%branch%" /v Model /d "%model%" /f
reg add "%branch%" /v Manufacturer /d "%manufacturer%" /f
```

or

```js
>>regfile.reg echo "Model"="%model%"
>>regfile.reg echo "Manufacturer"="%manufacturer%"
```